# ProgressBar setVisibility doesn´t work

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a asynchtask for some database operation

Before I start the task I call this function, to show a prograssBar
The ProgressBar is in a RelativLayout because someone on the net says that calling `setVisibility();` on the progressBar doesn´t work in some chases (and it doesn´t for me either)

```
 public static void showProgressBar()
{
    Log.e("TEST","Try to show ProgressBar, Visibiliy: " + prog_bar.getVisibility());
    if(prog_bar != null)
    {
        prog_bar.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
        Log.e("TEST","Success");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e("TEST","prog_bar != null");
    }
    Log.e("TEST","Visibiliy: " + prog_bar.getVisibility());
}
```

on PostExecute i call the function:

```
 public static void hideProgressBar()
{
    Log.e("TEST","Try to hide ProgressBar, Visibiliy: " + prog_bar.getVisibility());
    if(prog_bar != null)
    {
        prog_bar.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
        Log.e("TEST","Success");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e("TEST","prog_bar != null");
    }
    Log.e("TEST","Visibiliy: " + prog_bar.getVisibility());
}
```

Strange thing is that the methods are called correct, also the Logs are correct and no error appears, but no progressBar shows up.

Android  2.2,
Windows 7,
Tested on Emulator and GalaxyTab

Best regards schwandi

EDIT:

Changed my methods to:

```
  public static void hideProgressBar()
{

    if(prog_bar != null)
    {
        Log.e("TEST","Try to hide ProgressBar, Visibiliy: " + prog_bar.getVisibility());
        prog_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.e("TEST","Success");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e("TEST","prog_bar != null");
    }
    Log.e("TEST","Visibiliy: " + prog_bar.getVisibility());
}

public static void showProgressBar()
{

    if(prog_bar != null)
    {
        Log.e("TEST","Try to show ProgressBar, Visibiliy: " + prog_bar.getVisibility());
        prog_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.e("TEST","Success");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e("TEST","prog_bar != null");
    }
    Log.e("TEST","Visibiliy: " + prog_bar.getVisibility());
}
```

still doens´t work.

Also i changed that prog_bar is the ProgressBar itself.

```
  prog_bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
```

Comment: sorry men but this is progressBar not progressDialog, there is no such method like show or dismiss.

Comment: thanks, for your answers. i changed my code a litte bit, you can see the new one above. But it still doesn´t work

Comment: @Tim sorry it was my mistake by mistake.......... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your whole block of code initiating the `asyncTask` into a worker thread like this (leave out the `onClick()` if that's not relevant):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            // your entire asyncTask initiation code block here

        }
    }).start();
}
```

[Here is how it solved my own problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40767263/1827488) & here are [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads).