# Android progressBar setVisibility() not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar, countdowntimer, android-toast

Can someone please help me understand why `progressBar.setVisibility()` works when using a `CountDownTimer` but not when doing `async` download? In fact, the first `Toast` on `async` download does not even show even though the second one `onPostExecute()` does. Below is a working, or rather NOT working, demo. Thanks a lot.

My **MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    int[] items = { 12982418, 12998698, 12993549, 12995125, 12987537, 12993021, 12991986, 13008408, 12983417, 12986060, 12998395, 12985644, 13014731, 12986433, 12985074, 12994455, 12994262, 12986759, 13011932, 13005211, 12993521, 12987900, 12992623, 12981736, 12986649, 12991524, 13000035, 12989278, 13013868, 13009417, 13013327, 12981605, 12985768, 13000158, 13015035, 13002596, 13015944, 12997893, 12999767, 13010949, 12996835, 13013517, 13006555, 13013143, 13010016, 13005792, 13016948, 13007235, 12998343, 12987102 };
    int counter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressBar.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public void actionTimer(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "starting progressBar - CountDownTimer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new CountDownTimer(5000, 500) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "timer done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void actionJson(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "starting progressBar - json fetch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        String urlTemplate = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/___ITEM_NUMBER___.json?print=pretty";
        counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            String url = urlTemplate.replaceAll("___ITEM_NUMBER___", String.valueOf(items[i]));
            //Log.i("thisDoesNotWork", url);

            DownloadJson downloadJson = new DownloadJson();
            try {
                downloadJson.execute(url).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class DownloadJson extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.i("DownloadJson", "url=" + params[0]);

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(params[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    resultBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                //Log.i("DownloadJson", "resultBuilder.length()=" + resultBuilder.length());
                return resultBuilder.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "{\"status\" : \"Hacker News json download failed\"}";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            counter += 1;
            if (counter == items.length) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "download done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My **XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.plaudev.progressbar.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <Button
            android:text="@string/timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/buttonTimer"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="actionTimer"
            android:layout_margin="25dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="@string/json"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonJson"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="actionJson"
            android:layout_margin="25dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How long does your doInBackground task take to complete?  It could be that it's completing and the progress bar is set to invisible before it's even visible in the UI

Comment: onPostExecute run on UI thread means He is right . Instead of inVisible try with GONE. In your case you should always use gone

Comment: thank you both. I've already tried GONE but that does not work. Btw that does not explain why CountDownTimer method works with same INVISIBLE. The download completes in a matter of seconds.

Comment: Are you sure ` if (counter == items.length)` it passes?

Comment: just to be clear, the problem is the progressBar not showing up when the async download button is pressed

Comment: where is download button implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to put the whole `for` loop in the onClick `actionJson()` into a worker thread as follows as [noted here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads):

```
public void actionJson(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "starting progressBar - json fetch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final String urlTemplate = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/___ITEM_NUMBER___.json?print=pretty";
        counter = 0;

        // simply put it in a worker thread does the job
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    String url = urlTemplate.replaceAll("___ITEM_NUMBER___", String.valueOf(items[i]));
                    //Log.i("actionJson", url);
                    DownloadJson downloadJson = new DownloadJson();
                    try {
                        downloadJson.execute(url).get();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

So even though the `for` loop as originally defined does spawn a whole bunch of `asyncTasks` individually, it is still somehow blocking the main thread.